# Is a Singleton, a factory or something else better for this case?

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, singleton

I'm trying to find the best OO way to do this, and I would appreciate your help on it.

I think the simplest way is to show you how I've done it and try to explain what I want after (I simplified it) :

```
abstract public class MyServiceApi {
    private static MyServiceApi instance = null;

    public static <T extends MyServiceApi> T getInstance(Class<T> cls) {
        if (instance == null) {
            try {
                instance = cls.newInstance();
            }
            catch (InstantiationException e) {}
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        }

        return (T) instance;
    }

    private private HashMap<String, String> headers;

    protected MyServiceApi() {}

    public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    protected <T extends IMyServiceApiResponse> T send(String url, IMyServiceApiRequest request, Class<T> to) {
        // Do some stuffs

        // IMPORTANT : Also set headers to the request
    }

    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return "http://api.mywebsite.com/";
    }
}

public class UsersApi extends MyServiceApi {
    public static UsersApi getInstance() {
        return getInstance(UsersApi.class);
    }

    protected UsersApi() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return super().getBaseUrl() + "Users/";
    }

    // mutliple function that calls a specific URL in the API, and return specifics object based on the call, for example :
    public MyServiceApiUsersResponse getUsers(MyServiceApiUsersRequest request) {
        return send(getBaseUrl() + "get", request, MyServiceApiUsersResponse.class);
    }
}

public class ItemsApi extends MyServiceApi {
    public static ItemsApi getInstance() {
        return getInstance(ItemsApi.class);
    }

    protected ItemsApi() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return super().getBaseUrl() + "Items/";
    }

    // mutliple function that calls a speicfic URL in the API, and return specifics object based on the call, for example :
    public MyServiceApiItemsResponse getUsers(MyServiceApiItemsRequest request) {
        return send(getBaseUrl() + "get", request, MyServiceApiItemsResponse.class);
    }

}
```

Now that you have the idea, I'm stuck for something.

First of all, I don't know if what I did is correct (in a Java OO way). I think it's not bad, but I lack the experience to be sure.

Second of all, once my project is running, `MyServiceApi` will keep the same headers, I won't call other API or with other credentials. That's why I thought about the Singleton : I set the headers at my application start, and then I just have to do the request.
But I believe having `UsersApi` and `ItemsApi` extending `MyServiceApi` is the best way to do. They use `MyServiceApi`, they don't extends its capabilities.
Also, I eard that SingleTon are anti-pattern, bad for tests, etc.

So now I'm loose and I don't know what to do. How would you do that?

A possible idea is to remove the abstract of `MyServiceApi` and set a Singleton on it, having `UsersApi` and `ItemsApi` to use `MyServiceApi` but not by extending it, but how would I manage the getBaseUrl then ?

Thank you really much for your help, I really appreciate!

Comment: For your consideration - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil

Comment: Singletons are not an antipattern. Improper use of singletons is. Improper means almost always.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations. I think singletons are hated because it's the first design pattern OO developers learns, and often make mistakes about it (Singleton with multiple parameters, etc). That was also the purpose of my question : to be sure of not making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write it

```
enum MyServiceApi {
    UsersApi {
        public MyServiceApiUsersResponse getUsers(MyServiceApiUsersRequest request) {
            return send(getBaseUrl() + "Users/get", request, MyServiceApiUsersResponse.class);
        }

    },  ItemsApi {
        // mutliple function that calls a speicfic URL in the API, and return specifics object based on the call, for example :
        public MyServiceApiItemsResponse getUsers(MyServiceApiItemsRequest request) {
            return send(getBaseUrl() + "Items/get", request, MyServiceApiItemsResponse.class);
        }
    };

    private final Map<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers.clear();
        this.headers.putAll(headers);
    }

    public abstract <T extends IMyServiceApiResponse> T send(String url, IMyServiceApiRequest request, Class<T> to);

    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return "http://api.mywebsite.com/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Enum? That's odd! :) Where do I implement send then (if it's abstract) ?

Comment: Next to the `getUsers` methods in each instance.  It doesn't have to be abstract, its just an example.

Comment: I didn't exactly used your solutions but it oriented me to a correct singleton mode in a multithreaded environment. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dependency Injection rather than a Singleton.

It looks like you're trying to have a single service that has a base URL and sets up your headers.

Using Dependency Injection, create a service called MyApiService, much like you have and have UsersApi and ItemsApi depend on it as in:

```
public class MyServiceApi {

    private final String baseUrl;
    private final HashMap<String, String> headers;

    protected MyServiceApi(String baseUrl, HashMap<String, String> headers) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    protected <T extends IMyServiceApiResponse> T send(String url,
            IMyServiceApiRequest request, Class<T> to) {
        // Do some stuffs

        // IMPORTANT : Also set headers to the request
    }

    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return baseUrl;
    }
}

public class UsersApi {

    private final MyServiceApi myServiceApi;

    protected UsersApi(MyServiceApi myServiceApi) {
        this.myServiceApi = myServiceApi;
    }

    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return myServiceApi.getBaseUrl() + "Users/";
    }

    // mutliple function that calls a specific URL in the API, and return
    // specifics object based on the call, for example :
    public MyServiceApiUsersResponse getUsers(
            MyServiceApiUsersRequest request) {
        return myServiceApi.send(getBaseUrl() + "get", request,
                MyServiceApiUsersResponse.class);
    }
}
```

A few other things you could do:

- Create an interface that both MyServiceApi and UsersApi implements if you want to expose getBaseUrl consistently
- Have a look at some of the information about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) out there

Comment: Nice one ! I like it! I'll wait a bit if there is an alternative before accepting it, but yours is really good ! :)

Comment: Well I have question then : If I use this, then should I put a singleton in my `MyServiceApi` class to always have it the same through all my project (and so, removing the constructors parameters, and adding getters/setters) ?

Comment: Well I'm thinking a bit out loud, but if I do it with a singleton, I should just ignore the Dependency injection and call something like `return myServiceApi.getInstance().send(..)` in my `UsersApi` or `ItemsApi`, right?

Comment: I'd advise not using a Singleton as it will tightly couple your classes and make testing harder but otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for your awareness. If you are using Singleton pattern your getInstance method should be synchronized. Think a scenario where you have multiple threads running.For an example if one thread checked the instance is null and since it is null it will go inside the try block.Lets say it halts and the second thread comes to running state. And still the instance is null and it also have the opportunity to go inside the try block. then ultimately you will end up with two instances and you Singleton strategy will break

Comment: Interesting. How would you do then to avoid that kind of problem?

Comment: Following is the java implementation for it                      `public static synchronized SingletonPattern getInstance(){
  if (instance == null)
  {
  instance = new SingletonPattern();
  }
  return instance;
  }`